# Sort a PHP generated form by price

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort a PHP generated form by price. I get an error message 'Notice: Undefined index: PriceDesc/Asc'. I understand the error message but can't find any relevant info through searching so thought I'd ask. I'm new to PHP and so far this is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!--[if IE]>
  <link href="blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <![endif]-->
  <link href="blueprint/screen.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Enygma Peripherals</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div id="top" class="span-24">
        <div id="logo" class="span-5">
            <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Enygma"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="nav" class="span-11 last">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.php">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="mainContent" class="span-24">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <div id="left" class="span-8">
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="span-15 last">
            <form method="get" name="sort">
                <select name="sort" id="sort">
                    <option value="">--Select--</option>
                    <option value='PriceAsc'>Price: Highest First</option>
                    <option value='PriceDesc'>Price: Lowest First</option> 
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Sort"/>
            </form>
            <?php
                include("connection.php");

                $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
                IF ($_GET['PriceAsc']){
                    $orderby=" ORDER BY price ASC";
                } 
                IF ($_GET['PriceDesc']){
                    $orderby=" ORDER BY price DESC";
                }
                Print "<table border cellpadding=10>"; 
                while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
                { 
                Print "<tr>"; 
                Print "<th>Product Number:</th> <td>".$info['product_no'] . "</td> "; 
                Print "<th>Product:</th> <td>".$info['product_name'] . "</td> "; 
                Print "<th>Type:</th> <td>".$info['type'] . "</td> "; 
                Print "<th>Price:</th> <td>".$info['price'] . "</td> "; 
                Print "<th>Availability:</th> <td>".$info['availability'] . " </td></tr>"; 
                } 
                Print "</table>"; 
                ?>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="span-24">
        <a href="acknowledgements.html">Acknowledgments</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the record, I'm using PhpMyAdmin for my backend d/b and the initial tabled data works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
            IF ($_GET['PriceAsc']){
                $orderby =" ORDER BY price ASC";
            } 
            IF ($_GET['PriceDesc']){
                $orderby =" ORDER BY price DESC";
            }
```

with

```
if ( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceAsc' ) {
    $orderby=" ORDER BY price ASC";
} 
if ( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'PriceDesc' ) {
    $orderby=" ORDER BY price DESC";
}

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products".$orderby);
```

Note the changes, you need to use empty() to check if form submitted and check the value of it. And do the query once Order by appended to SQL.

Comment: where are you using `$orderby`? you need to put that in the query.

Comment: The error messages are gone. However the data still doesn't sort appropriately. In phpMyAdmin the 'price' column is in the format of '&pound;xx.xx'. will this affect it?

Answer (score 0):

You never attached the `$orderby` variable to the query. Try this:

```
            $data1 ="SELECT * FROM products";
            IF ($_GET['PriceAsc']){
                $data1 .=" ORDER BY price ASC";
            } 
            IF ($_GET['PriceDesc']){
                $data1 .=" ORDER BY price DESC";
            $data = mysql_query($data1);
```

The `.=` appends the string to the end of `$data`

And reason you getting the undefined index error is because theres no `PriceAsc` available! Youre trying to `$_GET` something that doesnt exist.

What you need to do is :

```
 IF ($_GET['sort'] == 'Price: Highest First'){
                    $data1 .=" ORDER BY price ASC";
                } else { 
                    $data1 .=" ORDER BY price DESC";
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error message 'Notice: Undefined index: PriceAsc' Notice: Undefined index: PriceDesc'

Comment: if you omit those variables from the URL, that's the notice you will get. use `array_key_exists` or `isset` to avoid the warning.

Comment: Are you sure youre not missing something in the code? Because you never even attached the order by to the query, so mysql cant get tht info..

Comment: @JonahKatz: according to this code, `$data` would be a MySQL result, not a query string. Appending the order by SQL to it would not work.

Comment: @Mark Good point, i overlooked that he ran `mysql_query` within that variable

Comment: I thought I had to link PriceAsc and PriceDesc (values in the form) into the $_GET global to pull the user selection out?

Answer (score 0):

Yes append the $sort to the $data as above

and you'll need those query strings to be coming in correctly with the url

```
http://www/mypage.php?PriceAsc=true
```

and you'll need to compare it correctly

```
 if ($_GET['PriceAsc']=='true'){
```